# ReiserFS warning: reiserfs_get_unused_objectid: no more object ids

Tags: linux, partition, reiserfs

I've a partition in ReiserFS which stores images from a camera (so it keeps adding/removing directories with pictures...).  When doing a dmesg, I get the following "warnings":

> [227297.192297] ReiserFS: md0:
>   warning: reiserfs_get_unused_objectid:
>   no more object ids [227297.604575]
>   ReiserFS: md0: warning:
>   reiserfs_get_unused_objectid: no more
>   object ids

So, it seems some kind of counter has run out of "numbers"?  Any thoughts if that counter could be reseted?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

[reiserfsck](http://linux.die.net/man/8/reiserfsck)

But my advice is backup your whole partition first (and better on the block layer).

Comment: Have you encountered that problem too? Or that's the only tool you know to deal with ReiserFS problems? Thanks a lot :)

Comment: Nope, never met this. But it's the only approved tool, yeah. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Try a `df -i` command. The file system on which your files reside may be out of inodes. This occurs if lots and lots and lots of itty-bitty files are created. They use up inodes but very little disk space.

Unfortunately, you can't add inodes to a file system. Instead, you have to clean out the small files.

Edit: Oy! Ignore my comment. As kasperd correctly points out, Inodes on Reiser filesystems are not persistent.

Comment: That is certainly true of some file systems. But this question is about reiserfs. The entire point of reiserfs was to not have such restrictions.

Comment: Hi An Old Retired Guy, please goto [Help Center > Contact](http://serverfault.com/contact) select "I need to merge user profiles" .